# Can we get the data based on the foreign keys in the changed_fields column?

Tags: postgresql, audit-logging

After creating the trigger on "Calls" table, I'm able to get the data of that exact column of that table when I perform any CRUD operations on that table.

Here, my "changed_fields" column now consists of the data like `"callstatusid"=> 3`.

What I want is to get the description/name of the Status from the "StatusMaster" table, StatusId of which is the FK to the callstatusid in the "Calls" table.

Status table structure:

```
 Id  | Name
 1   | New  
 2   | In-progress  
 3   | Review  
 4   | Completed
```

Expected string to be saved in the table: `"callstatusid"=>"Review"`

SQL Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit.if_modified_func_MyTable() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $body$
DECLARE
    audit_row audit.logged_actions_MyTable;
    include_values boolean;
    log_diffs boolean;
    h_old hstore;
    h_new hstore;
    excluded_cols text[] = ARRAY[]::text[];
BEGIN
    IF TG_WHEN <> 'AFTER' THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'audit.if_modified_func_MyTable() may only run as an AFTER trigger';
    END IF;

    audit_row = ROW(
        nextval('audit.logged_actions_MyTable_event_id_seq'), -- event_id
        TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::text,                        -- schema_name
        TG_TABLE_NAME::text,                          -- table_name
        TG_RELID,                                     -- relation OID for much quicker searches
        session_user::text,                           -- session_user_name
        current_timestamp,                            -- action_tstamp_tx
        statement_timestamp(),                        -- action_tstamp_stm
        clock_timestamp(),                            -- action_tstamp_clk
        txid_current(),                               -- transaction ID
        current_setting('application_name'),          -- client application
        inet_client_addr(),                           -- client_addr
        inet_client_port(),                           -- client_port
        current_query(),                              -- top-level query or queries (if multistatement) from client
        substring(TG_OP,1,1),                         -- action
        NULL, NULL,                                   -- row_data, changed_fields
        'f'                                           -- statement_only
        );

    IF NOT TG_ARGV[0]::boolean IS DISTINCT FROM 'f'::boolean THEN
        audit_row.client_query = NULL;
    END IF;

    IF TG_ARGV[1] IS NOT NULL THEN
        excluded_cols = TG_ARGV[1]::text[];
    END IF;

    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW') THEN
        audit_row.row_data = hstore(OLD.*) - excluded_cols;
        audit_row.changed_fields =  (hstore(NEW.*) - audit_row.row_data) - excluded_cols;
        audit_row.MyTableid = (old."MyTableid");
        audit_row.modifiedon =  Now();
        audit_row.modifiedby = (select firstname || ' ' || lastname  as name from public.Users where userid=(old."modifiedby"));
        audit_row.ActualField =  (hstore(old.*) - (audit_row.row_data - ((hstore(old.*)) - (hstore(NEW.*))) ));
            -- ActualField is taken to get old values of only the columns which have been changed and not all the columns.

        IF audit_row.changed_fields = hstore('') THEN
            -- All changed fields are ignored. Skip this update.
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE' AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW') THEN
        audit_row.row_data = hstore(OLD.*) - excluded_cols;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT' AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW') THEN
        audit_row.row_data = hstore(NEW.*) - excluded_cols;
    ELSIF (TG_LEVEL = 'STATEMENT' AND TG_OP IN ('INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE','TRUNCATE')) THEN
        audit_row.statement_only = 't';
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION '[audit.if_modified_func_MyTable] - Trigger func added as trigger for unhandled case: %, %',TG_OP, TG_LEVEL;
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO audit.logged_actions_MyTable VALUES (audit_row.*);
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
SET search_path = pg_catalog, public;
```

Comment: can you share your existing trigger code?

Comment: @richyen Added the SQL above.